# Click effect on button in Android (which is available in older android API)

Tags: android, button, effect

I am new to android studio .I need some effect on Button so user can recognize that button is clicked. Button should be dark while a few second when it clicked , so what should I do for this ?  please help me...

Ripple effect(drawable v-21) is not available in older android API.

here is my ripple.xml. which is not support in older android API.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/colorAccent">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask"
    android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</ripple>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style="?selectableItemBackground" it will show shadow and ripple effect on button click. I hope this will help you

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="Button"
    style="?selectableItemBackground"
    />
```